# New changes do not appear in bin debug

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a windows form application.
Few days ago I started making it look better by changing icons and images.
But the changes do not appear on my form. (imagelist and program logo .ico)
I have built/cleaned my application several times.
Is there something else I should clean?

Comment: Have you changed the configuration of the project from Debug?

Comment: When you generate the project, does it compile without problems?

Comment: silly question: are you building it in debug mode?

Comment: yes i'm building in debug mode. / how do you change the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are compiling to Debug and not Release
2. Make sure you have the same platform (x86, x64, Any CPU) than before.

If still problems:

1. Clean solution
2. Delete bin and obj folders.
3. Rebuild

Also, its a good practice to have images and icons in resources. If you don't you can give it a try.

**Update**

Are you sure the app is compiling? You might have said to run even with errors and checked to not ask you again. Go to `View` menu -> `Error list` and see if there is any compiling error.

Comment: doesn't work. even when i run my app from visual studio the changes are not done.

Comment: Where are the images? How are you using them?

Comment: my logo image is currently on the desktop and not in the project folder. i can see it on my form in the solution but when i run my program the old logo is displaced in my window.

Comment: Try, as I said in my answer, to use resources. If you don't wont, at least include it in the proyect and set in the properties the `copy to output directory` to `copy always`

Comment: where can i set this 'copy to output'?

Comment: Select the image in the solution explorer, right click -> `Properties`

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that in the solution's properties the project is actually marked for build. You can - for every project in the solution - check a box saying whether the project should actually be built or not.

Comment: my solution's build action is "compile".

Comment: @Pedram Right click on solution, see properties. Go to configuration. There you see checkboxes across each project. Check everything to build, if it isnt as of now

Comment: even my program logo does not change while i'm seeing the logo there on my form before i run my program.

Comment: Did you change the build output folder? Maybe the executables are stored somewhere completely different?

Comment: i don't think that's the cause, i just cleaned and built everything again.

Comment: Do the timestamps of the files in the `bin\debug` folder change? When you clean, are files removed from the `bin\debug` folder? If not, the `bin\debug` folder is not currently in use.

Comment: i actually delete the bin/debug folders manually. and i see them being replaced when i clean and build the application. the problem is i cannot even see the changes when i'm inside visual studio. they are on my form but when i click start it's the old thing. strange. maybe i'm doing something really wrong and i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Any resources ( image files for example) must be added to the project and marked as copy to output folder ( always ) there is the option to copy if newer but since this is dependant on time stamps the first choice is more reliable.

Without this associated resource files will not end up in your build output folder.